# How to replace the text of an element with the value of another inside of a specific parent tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

High level: How do I replace the text of an element with the value of another inside of a specific parent tag?

Specific: Using the HTML below, I want to replace the html of "span.number" with the value of "input.someOtherNumber". I can have multipul of these list items on a page so it needs to be narrowed down using the parent.

```
<ul>
 <li class="list-item">
    <span class="number">0</span>
    <input class="someOtherNumber" type="text" value="10" />
 </li>

 <li class="list-item">
    <span class="number">0</span>
    <input class="someOtherNumber" type="text" value="99" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

The following JS works to replace the "span.number" value with the value of "inout.someOtherNumber" but it doesn't limit it to the parent. How can I limit it to the parent?

```
    $(".someOtherNumber").keyup(function () { 
      var value = $(this).val();
      $(".number").text(value);
    }).keyup();
```

EDIT:

If the input is wrapped in a span then how do I accomplish it? I am really looks for a solution that checks for a parent because in my real code I have multipul elements that can nested inside of each other so the ".sibling" or ".prev/.next" will not work. The updated HTML would look like this:

```
<ul>
 <li class="list-item">
    <span class="number">0</span>
    <span><input class="someOtherNumber" type="text" value="10" /></span>
 </li>

 <li class="list-item">
    <span class="number">0</span>
    <span><input class="someOtherNumber" type="text" value="99" /></span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8bXbx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(".someOtherNumber").keyup(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".number").text(this.value);
}).keyup();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/j9aaX/

Also, because `this` is a HTML Input element, you can just access the value using `this.value`

---

Just in reply to your comment. In order to get the element based on the common parent, you'd use `closest` to go up the tree to the parent element and then `children` to go back down the tree and get the element you want.

```
$(".someOtherNumber").keyup(function() {
    $(this).closest(".list-item").children(".number").text(this.value);
}).keyup();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/j9aaX/1/

Comment: what if it wasn't a direct sibling but still inside a common parent? In you example, if you wrap "<input class="someOtherNumber" type="text" value="99" />" inside of a span the solution breaks.

Comment: True, but the solution works for your original HTML :) In order to do what you're asking, you need to go up the tree to the 'common parent' and then back down to find the element you want. I've updated my answer to explain.

Comment: You are correct, your solution did answer my original question. I've edited my original question to reflect my comment. Thanks for the help and the new solution.

Comment: I ended up using .find instead of .children as I had even more nesting in my real code than in my example here.

Answer (score 5):

Replace:

```
$(".number").text(value);
```

With:

```
$(this).prev(".number").text(value);
```

..fredrik

Comment: This does work but what if the input is wrapped in another element such as a span?